# how to change the name of `key` field to value of key in dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I want to change the name of `key` field to value of the key and replace the value of `value` field with value of `key` field.

this is my class

```
public class SearchResponse 
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

response is like this:

```
{
    "key":"aaaa",
    "value":123
}
```

but I want the response to be like this

```
{
    "aaaa":123
}
```

is there a way?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ OP doesn't need to reverse a dictionary, the point is get a key/value pair from two values in original dictionary

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Oops, my bad. Thanks for clearing. Seems like I misunderstood the question. Retracting my close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse response into [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then add new token with values from existing tokens and remove the old ones

```cs
var json = "{\"key\":\"aaaa\",\"value\":123}";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
jObject[jObject["key"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty] = jObject["value"];
jObject.Remove("key");
jObject.Remove("value");
Console.WriteLine(jObject);
```

Output will be the following

```
{
  "aaaa": 123
}
```

You can place the code above into the loop, if you have multiple items. Then you can convert `JObject` to the dictionary of required type, using `ToObject<T>()` method

```
var dict = jObject.ToObject<Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

Also, keep in mind that your initial reponse doesn't match `Dictionary<string, int>` type, because `"key":"aaaa"` has a `string` value, not the `int`.

Another and more generic way is to parse json into `Dictionary<string,string>`,  and then add every pair of values as key and value to a new `Dictionary<string, int>`

```cs
var json = "{\"key\":\"aaaa\",\"value\":123}";
var dict = JObject.Parse(json).ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i += 2)
{
    var first = dict.ElementAt(i);
    var second = dict.ElementAt(i + 1);

    result.Add(first.Value, int.TryParse(second.Value, out int parsedValue) ? parsedValue : 0);
}
```

Comment: how can i use the  `JObject` in `wcf`? when i use `JObject` in `wcf` the response is not showed!

Comment: @FarhadZamani ensure, that you have a correct response in a correct format. Or create a new question with this specific problem. No response doesn't mean a problem with code, most probably you aren't receiving a correct response

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ModelToDict<T>(T item)
    {
        Type myObjectType = item.GetType();
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = myObjectType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var info in properties)
        {
            string value = (string)info.GetValue(item);
            dict.Add(info.Name, value);//change the order if you like
        }
        return dict;
    }
```